# list.append() of strings in a loop

Tags: string, list, loops, types

I have a source file that looks like this:

```
okay \t ADJ \t okay 
apple \t N \t apple 
etc.
```

I try to filter out the 2nd and the 3rd columns, starting with a letter and where all the lines containing '\', '&' and the string '(unknown)' should be excluded. If I write it to a new file the code works perfectly fine. However, I try to save the whole columns as a list, there seems to be a problem.

Could someone help me where the error of reasoning is?

```
with open(path_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            lemma = []
            if re.match('[A-Z]|[a-z]', line):
                line = line.strip()
                columns = line.split('\t')
                pos = columns[1]
                lemmas = columns[2]
                lemma.append(lemmas)
                # print type(lemmas)
                # type - str
                if '(unknown)' in lemmas:
                    pass
                elif '\\' in lemmas:
                    pass
                elif '&' in lemmas:
                    pass
                else:
                    lemma.append(lemmas)
                    # outfile.write(str(lemmas) + ':::' + str(pos) + '\n')
```

I am using python 2.

Comment: Could you give a sample output that you expect? Don't fully understand your question.

Comment: so the output that I expect is a list with all the words from the 3rd column for example. That would be like this: lemma = ['okay', 'apple' etc]. However if I run it, in the end, the list contains just 1 word. I guess, this code just updates the lists and does not 'append' the words during every iteration. I think this has to do with the types and the iteration itself, but I cannot figure out where I did the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run your code. With that example input it works.

```
with open(path_file, 'r') as f:
    lemma = []
    for line in f:
        if re.match('[A-Z]|[a-z]', line):
            line = line.strip()
            print('line:', line)
            columns = line.split('\\t')
            pos = columns[1]
            lemmas = columns[2]
            lemma.append(lemmas.strip())
            # type - str
            if '(unknown)' in lemmas:
                pass
            elif '\\' in lemmas:
                pass
            elif '&' in lemmas:
                pass
#            else:
#                lemma.append(lemmas)
                # outfile.write(str(lemmas) + ':::' + str(pos) + '\n')
    print(lemma)
```

You need to place the `lemma` list above the for loop, because you reinitialize it as empty list during every iteration, i.e. new line of the input file.

Then I commented out the `else` statement.

Also I put `\\t` instead of `\t` in the `split` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are great, it does what it needs to do now, thank you!